# Python 'called with the wrong argument type' error

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyside, pyside2

I understand why I am getting this error, it's looking for my object as an argument, and receiving a string value. But I'm confused as to what the solution would be?

The following code snippet is simply trying to run this command;

```
self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.ui.m001)
```

x number of times:

```
num = 0
range_ = 10
prefix = "m"

for i in range (range_):
    if num <(range_-1):
        numString = "00"+str(num)
        if (num >9):
            numString = "0"+str(num)

        button = "self.ui."+prefix+numString

        self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)
        num +=1

print self.buttonGroup
```

Comment: Save everything in a dict or list, not as individual variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that button is a string, a possible solution is to use `getattr`.

Change:

```
button = "self.ui."+prefix+numString
```

to

```
button = getattr(self.ui, prefix+numString)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I was looking at getattr as a solution but wasn't able to put it together,  until I saw your example.